# How to send image dat over network as fast ?

Tags: java, android

I am working with client-server using Java. Client is performs on android and wants to request some images from server. And the server will response image as byte[] data to client. The approximate size of data is 150K per/request (already re-size). And the process usually use 3 seconds for response. I think it use long time to response client.

Could anyone guide me as trick for use shorter time response?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with mobile networks, there is no guaranteed network speed. The best that can be done is (as you said) resizing and then having a strong compression applied to the image. You will find that in some areas (including some cities) your response time will be over 20secs due to poor signal quality and congested networks.

Answer (score 1):

Use GZIP compression compression